# Count number of word in string which is having html tags

Tags: java

Consider following string which has html tag

```
"<p>Article</p> <p>Article</p> <p>Article</p> <p>&nbsp</p>";
```

Now i want to count number of word contained in above mentioned string

It produce worong output

Instead of 3 word count it displays 4 word count

It consider `<p>&nbsp</p>` as word which is wrong

**Please correct following program**

```
String str = "<p>Article</p> <p>Article</p> <p>Article</p> <p>&nbsp</p>";
org.jsoup.nodes.Document dom = Jsoup.parse(str);
String str2 = dom.text();
System.out.println(str2.split(" ").length);
```

**What changes should i made to get correct output?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is a semicolon missing for &nbsp.It should be &nbsp;

Comment: I tried by adding semicolon (&nbsp;) but same issue.. :( still give 4

Answer (score 0):

As Benjamin mentioned in the comment, the after &nbsp, you should add a semicolon ( ). If you do not add it, the it cannot parse it based on the instructions because it is thought as "one element", which you do not want.